# FastAPI database SQL

Tags: python, sql, database, fastapi

I has a FastAPI project where I have main.py, endpoints.py (with endpoint functions) and users_db.py where I have list of dictionaries. Every dictionary save users data. It just pet project to understand web application. An now I want to create database. I chose SQL. Can somebody explaine or give a link where is described how to do that?! Or is it very hard?!

Comment: Here is a repo with multiple examples on how to implement a database: [repo](https://github.com/scionoftech/FastAPI-Full-Stack-Samples/tree/master/FastAPISQLAlchamy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very simple.

**first you need install sqlalchemy**

`pip install SQLAlchemy`

then create database.py file and paste the following code to that.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./sql_app.db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

then create **models.py** file and write some database models you need.

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .database import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users" # this is table name

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
```

Read the documentation for more information.
[documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/)

Comment: Should I create class User in model.py?! I don't understand it apsolutely. I know what is calss and so on... But I cant understand how to unite my users = [{},{}] with model and schemas and so on

Comment: Actually this is not a rule, you can create your class anywhere you want, but for better understanding it's recommended to create your database models in modles.py file. For your second question, you create a model and schema and store your users in the database and then you can retrieve your users and show it.
in schema you define what fileds you want to return from your database, i recommend to you, read the documentation or watch a course in youtube for better understanding.